# How to collect tweets/retweets using GNIP API in php

Tags: php, twitter, streaming, gnip

Since twitter has switched to streaming his API, we have to collect the data by ourselves. 
How we can do it using GNIP API in php?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this, I’ve just wanted to ensure that I’ve done everything right and maybe to improve my `TwitterGnipClient` class with your help.
But if there are no answers, let it be FAQ style question.

Main methods see below:

```
/**
 * Add rules to PowerTrack stream’s ruleset.
 * @example ['id' => 'url', ...]
 * @param array $data
 */
public function addRules(array $data)
{
    $rules = [];
    foreach ($data as $id => $url) {
        $rules[] = $this->buildRuleForUrl($url, $id);
    }
    $this->httpClient->post($this->getRulesUrl(), [
        'auth' => [$this->getUser(), $this->getPassword()],
        'json' => ['rules' => $rules]
    ]);
}
/**
 * Retrieves all existing rules for a stream.
 * @return \Generator
 */
public function getRules()
{
    $response = $this->httpClient->get($this->getRulesUrl(), [
        'auth' => [$this->getUser(), $this->getPassword()]
    ]);
    $batchStr = '';
    $body = $response->getBody();
    while (!$body->eof()) {
        $batchStr .= $body->read(1024);
    }
    $batchArray = explode(PHP_EOL, $batchStr);
    unset($batchStr);
    foreach ($batchArray as $itemJson) {
        yield $this->unpackJson($itemJson);
    }
}
/**
 * Removes the specified rules from the stream.
 * @param $data
 */
public function deleteRules($data)
{
    $rules = [];
    foreach ($data as $id => $url) {
        $rules[] = $this->buildRuleForUrl($url, $id);
    }
    $this->httpClient->delete($this->getRulesUrl(), [
        'auth' => [$this->getUser(), $this->getPassword()],
        'json' => ['rules' => array_values($rules)]
    ]);
}
/**
 * Open stream through which the social data will be delivered.
 * @return \Generator
 */
public function listenStream()
{
    $response = $this->httpClient->get($this->getStreamUrl(), [
        'auth' => [$this->getUser(), $this->getPassword()],
        'stream' => true
    ]);
    $batchStr = '';
    $body = $response->getBody();
    while (!$body->eof()) {
        $batchStr .= $body->read(1024);
        $batchArray = explode(PHP_EOL, $batchStr);
        // leave the last piece of response as it can be incomplete
        $batchStr = array_pop($batchArray);
        foreach ($batchArray as $itemJson) {
            yield $this->processBroadcastItem($this->unpackJson($itemJson));
        }
    }
    $body->close();
}
/**
 * Process broadcast item data
 * @param $data
 * @return array
 */
protected function processBroadcastItem($data)
{
    if (is_array($data)) {
        $url = str_replace('url_contains:', '', $data['gnip']['matching_rules'][0]['value']);
        switch ($data['verb']) {
            // Occurs when a user posts a new Tweet.
            case 'post':
                return $this->getMappedResponse($url, 'tweet', 1);
                break;
            // Occurs when a user Retweets another user's Tweet
            case 'share':
                return $this->getMappedResponse($url, 'retweet', $data['retweetCount']);
                break;
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

All class I shared as Gist - [here](https://gist.github.com/ddimitrioglo/dfe3b0f049567c3541ee97262d999470)

P.S. If you see an evident issue - comment it please.